# Fullpage.js - Setting fadingEffect only on certain sections

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm trying to set my site to work with the default Fullpage.js scroll behaviour until it gets to certain point, then switch to using the fadeEffect plugin. According to the docs I can determine whether the effect is applied to either Sections or Slides but there's no advice on selecting only certain sections.

> fadingEffect: (default false). Extension of fullpage.js. Defines whether to use a fading effect or not instead of the default scrolling one. Possible values are true, false, sections, slides. It can therefore be applied just vertically or horizontally, or to both at the time. It can only be used when using: autoScrolling:true. Requires fullpage.js >= 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is not suppose to be used that way.
Rather it is used for all vertical sections or for all horizontal ones, but you can't just decide if you want to use it only for a few vertical ones or a few horizontal ones.

The most you can do is enable and disable the effect on the `afterLoad` section/slide but that would only allow you to disable or enable it based on the section/slide you land and never before the movement takes place.

You can use the following methods to enable/disable the effect that are also present on the code of the [demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html):

```
    fullpage_api.fadingEffect.turnOn();
    fullpage_api.fadingEffect.turnOff();
```

But remember you won't be able to use them on the `onLave` or `onSlideLeave` callbacks.